# How to delete old data from CRM 2011 quickly?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We are using Bulk Deletion to delete old data from CRM 2011. It's a pre-requisite for our product to go online. But it's unexpectedly too slow. Is there any quicker way to do it?

The context is as below:

- We cannot touch the CRM Web server.
- We cannot touch the CRM DB server.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugins that are running on delete of the Product entity? You might look into if they can be turned off for a bulk delete.

Comment: If I turn off the plugins, will that speed up the bulk deletion?

Comment: Potentially, yes. The plugins add more work into the execution pipeline. How much time you save depends entirely on the plugin and what it is doing. It may be, of course, that you need the plugin to run and you cannot turn it off (in other words: beware!).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only plugins registered on the delete of the entity or one of the child entities would really effect it.

Comment: I've also struggled with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162534/how-to-improve-delete-timeout-issues-in-crm-2011-on-prem-dev-environment

Answer (score 1):

The bulk delete action uses the async CRM service which by its nature runs in the background. If you want to delete records faster then you could knock up a quick console application that issued delete requestes to the server one by one. If you are on RU12 or later then you can batch these together using the execute multiple syntax.